# jQuery is not working with JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, html, keypress

I am new to jQuery and just started learning, I have written this simplest code in jquery but it is not working

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello"); 
$('#_divTxtmyName_combo').keypress(function(event){alert("HI Samantha");})});
</script>
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be treating "#_divTxtmyName_combo' invalid as id of the element is starting with "_".

Try modifying it once and also include your java script files at the end of the body section and check whether it's working or not.

Comment: i have replaced  "#_divTxtmyName_combo'  with '.txtdiv' ...still not working.

Comment: have you tried placing your jquery code at the end of body section?

Comment: included your code in JSfiddle. It's absolutely working fine. Have a look at demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/N9bQf/2/

Comment: it only alerts "Hello" but not "Hi Samantha" on keypress... same issue that I am facing on my local system.

Comment: If alert("Hello") works, then jquery seems working for you. The problem is with firing the event.

Comment: I'm able to see alert on keypress also. AFter pressing any key i'm getting alert..I don't see any issue in jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0):

You want to fire the key press event for your tags inside your div.I am using a text box inside the div here. Try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello"); 
$('#_divTxtmyName_combo').keypress(function(event){alert("HI Samantha");})});
</script>


<div id="_divTxtmyName_combo">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Here, on pressing any key inside your text box this will fire the event..

Answer (score 0):

Normally,you have to use keypress event in input tag not with div tag.

if you need keypress event for div tag then you have to use tabindex properties

here is the code

```
<div id="#divTxtmyName" tabindex="1">      
    <p>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisis donec aliquam integer, cursus nulla metus. Libero neque feugiat in veniam nec, rutrum eros nec, penatibus amet ut accumsan. Quam ac nisi sempe

        </p>
</div>
```

jQuery Code :

```
$(function() {

$("#divTxtmyName")
    .on("keypress", keyAction)                           
}); 

function keyAction() {
            alert('hi');
        }
```

Example is here --->[Click here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zh5gw/)